# method `source' not defined in Gem::Specification (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

I have an issue with deploying app on my server with centos7. Everything works fine, capistrano ends with no error and app does't work on passenger.I'm getting error

```
method `source' not defined in Gem::Specification (NameError)
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:17:in `remove_method'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:17:in `<class:Specification>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:14:in `<module:Gem>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:10:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:361:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:525:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:378:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Before reinstalling my server i had the same problem but app was working for few days and then for few days this error and again working for few days without any of my fixes.

Comment: anything new???

Comment: yes, fixed. I set 2 different path to ruby